# Instagram API Javascript Example Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, instagram-api

I am trying to add a photo feed of my Instagram account using the following tutorial: http://instafeedjs.com/#user

Here is my html code with the instafeed.min.js file added:

```
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- link CSS and font files here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400italic,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
    <script src="js/instafeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var userFeed = new Instafeed ({
            get: "user",
            userId: "8169627"
        });
        userFeed.run();
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="my_life">       
        <h1>A look into my life</h1>
        <!-- Instragram photo feed -->
        <div id="instafeed"></div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here? The pictures are not showing up when I reload the page in my browser. Thanks in advance, Brian.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I just checked and there is an error. It says "Uncaught Error: Missing clientId or accessToken." Weird since I followed the exact instructions. The tutorial says I can use either the clientId or an accessToken.

Comment: It said you could use either one, but I don't see where you do. I see a userId, but no clientId. Sounds like you are not authenticating correctly so you can't retrieve the data.

Comment: My mistake...the API asks for a userId which I have inputted correctly. Then there is an error in the JS file saying that I'm missing a clientId or accessToken. I have both of those and tried them, but still no luck.

Comment: It said "missing clientId", then you gave it one, then it still said "missing clientId"? And also the same thing for accessToken?

Comment: I fixed the problem. Apparently you have to have all three specified, i.e. userId, clientId and accessToken. I'll post the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you have to have the userId, clientId and accessToken all specified to grab your Instagram photo feed. Below is the correct Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var userFeed = new Instafeed ({
            get: "user",
            userId: "8169627",
            clientId: "CLIENT_ID",
            accessToken: "ACCESS_TOKEN"
        });
        userFeed.run();
</script>
```

I removed my personal clientId and accessToken for security and privacy purposes.